# My code using Pandas Options did work - now throws an error

Tags: python, pandas

My previously working code now throws an error.  So I have now tried the code given in the Docs 0.15.1 for Options and this throws a similar error.

```
from pandas.io.data import Options

aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')

data = aapl.get_all_data()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-a2dc6d91ec5f>", line 1, in <module>
  data = aapl.get_all_data()

  File "C:\Users\Ray\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py", line 1111, in get_all_data
  m2 = month.month
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Comment: Think this is related to [this bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8612), which apparently resulted from Yahoo changing their page format.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Because this works in 0.15.1. It indeed broke for older versions (just after 0.15.0 was released) due to a Yahoo change, but this was fixed in 0.15.1