# Pandas Options Broken Again?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Running this canonical example:

```
from pandas.io.data import  Options

aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')
data = aapl.get_all_data()
```

gives

```
RemoteDataError: Data not available
```

I know this [used to be an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8612) in v0.14 or so, but it was [supposedly fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879082/my-code-using-pandas-options-did-work-now-throws-an-error) with v0.15.  I'm on 0.18.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Yahoo - [they've changed their options site](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/212), so old parsers aren't working properly

Suggestion: first of all consider using `pandas_datareader` instead of deprecated `pandas.io.data` and monitor [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/212) so you'll know when this issue is fixed